# J-Link GDB Server receving a connection by Python

Tags: python, automation, gdb, segger-jlink

Hello great people of the internets

I am using J-Link GDB Server to accept GDB clients and execute commands via J-link Commander.
I am using a fully automated python code that needs to send write and read requests to change/read registries in a perihfallical whitin the Cortex-M3. I can execute those commands in the J-Link Commander via mem32 and w4, but I want to connect to J-Link GDB Server via TCP/IP in python and send those requests.

How in gods name can I do this?
Thank you!